# Suppose f is uniformly continuous on I and J. Prove that if I intersecting J are non-empty, then f is uniformly continuous on I union J.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Problem: Let I and J be two non-degenerate intervals and suppose f is uniformly continuous on I and J. Prove that if I intersecting J are non-empty, then f is uniformly continuous on I union J.

I understand what non-degenerate means. But my thought was since f is uniformly continuous on I and J, then it is clearly uniformly continuous on I union J. This is incorrect though...Help!

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$, and $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$. $f$ is not even continuous on the union of these two intervals... so you do need the assumption on $I \cap J$.

Comment: Okay. Since I and J are subsets of real numbers. If x,y are in I and x,y are in J. Clearly, x,y is in I union J. So I don't realize what there is to prove.

Comment: You need to show it is uniformly continuous in $I\cup J$, not $I\cap J$. What if $x\in I$ and $y\in J$?

Comment: Oh okay, I see that now. I am stuck. Do you have a hint you can offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can suppose that $inf (I) \leq inf (J)$ without loss of generaliy.
For every $\epsilon > 0$ we are looking for $\delta >0$ such that if 
$|y-x| \leq \delta$  then  $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for every $x,y \in I \cup J$.

For given  $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $\delta_1 >0$ such that  $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon/2$ for every $x,y \in I$ such that $|y-x| \leq \delta_1$ and
$\delta_1 >0$ such that  $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon/2$ for every $x,y \in J$ such that $|y-x| \leq \delta_2$ . End finally we define $\delta := min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.

If $x,y \in I$ or $x,y \in J$ that is obviously correct.

If $x \in I$ and $y \in J$ , there is $x_0 \in I \cap J$ such that $x_0 \in (x,y)$ - because those intervals intersect nonempty.

We have $|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y)-f(x_0) + f(x_0)-f(x)| \leq 
|f(y)-f(x_0)| +| f(x_0)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon /2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon $
because $x,x_0 \in I$ and $x_0,y \in J$.

Comment: This is false. Because $f=x^2$ on$ I= [0,2]$ and $f=0$ on $J = [-2,0] \cup (2,4]$ consideirng the point 2, this is not continuous for I union J.